# Ember.js - How share route model-data between more routes? - Why not load data in component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

TL;DR
Embers components are just smart HTML-Templates. Why they don't fetch their data for themselves like Angular? And how I can share route models over more URLs/pages. It seems that I have to know wich components are placed on which URL and I have to make them the data available over the route models. Why is this part not in the component?

---

I learn at the moment Ember.js. I try at least.
At the moment I have a strong problem to understand why Ember.js acts like it does. Please correct me if I am wrong at some statements. I am an Ember.js beginner. So maybe its not right what I point out here.

Lets say we have a Request on `/` then Ember tries to find a route model in `app/routes/index.js` this file contains the code which data I want to fetch from the backend. Next Ember will render `app/templates/index.hbs` in this file I have a component called `car-list`.

As far no problems but let us have a closer look. For me it feels very weird that I have to fetch at first the data by myself, why the component doesn't do this on its own? Next problem is then how can I share the model fetch logic between more routes? Maybe I want to place my component on many URLs/pages/routes then I have to copy the route model logic?

In my opinion, the component should fetch the data by itself, that you can easily insert the component on other pages without copy the whole route model fetch logic.

So I have to know wich components are placed on which URL and I have to make them the data available over the route models. Why is this part not in the component?

So maybe I am just not good enough with Ember and I just overlook something?

Comment: After I read all official guides this question came up. This question is the results because I know the conventions and concepts. Correct me if I am wrong. After I read a lot of other articles beside Stack I can stay this issue is controversy dicussed. Some people in the Ember community think components should not be route dependent and should work on its own other people say follow Embers conventions and place it in the route.

Answer (score 3):

Components are very flexible. Components have made to be reusable. For example you can create a table component and use for cars, ships, etc.

So for reusability it's better you separate model providing from component.

But if you want to make a component which is for current project and need to fetch its data itself, you can fetch data in the component.

In some scenarios you might want to fetch data in routes. For example in your page you have multiple components and every component needs a projection of data model which fetched in route.

So it depends on your requirements, maybe you need to fetch data in component or in route or even both (mixed)

Comment: Okay good to know but how would you solve the following problem? Lets say we want to display the username on every page. I created a user-component, For me it seems so that the component should fetch the data here because I dont want to paste everytime the route-model-code into a new route-model-file that gets the data on every url. What would be the best practice in ember-structure?

Comment: @TatzyXY For this problem you need to use services. Ember services are singleton. You can fetch current user in user service after login and use it anywahere

Comment: I completely agree with your statement but why it is still then considered as bad practice when components load the data. Next question is then when it is considered as bad practice why we have that much convenience methodes in the component.

Comment: **bad practice when components load the data.** - because components are designed to be independent and reusable, not reusable only with one model, but reusable with many different models. Think of a graph component. If the graph gets the data in the component then you have to have a new graph component for each dataset, instead of one reusable component

Comment: It's true that it's bad practice, but we should have all that methods to load data. Consider your component show weather map with a customized graphics. Here model is weather info which be fetched from another site (google eg). So the component can fetch model itself.

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani routable components are in the road map for Ember.

Comment: @Craicerjack Yes. Now we don't have them yet

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I think the best way for my components is still to go over: `store: Ember.inject.service()` in my component even when it is considered as bad practice but in my opinion my components should not be route dependent. For Example a "Last Posts" or "Newest Comments". Components should be easy to place them everywhere, when they are route depdendent they aren´t, it would negate it´s existence. But it´s just my opinion.

Comment: @TatzyXY I agree. It depends on requirements

Answer (score 1):

Components certainly *can* load their own data, and in many cases that is appropriate. But allowing the route to load the data has several important benefits that you get "for free" if you stick to that pattern:

- your application's URL will always reflect the state of the data. You don't have to remember to synchronize it (in both directions -- changes to URL should change the data, and changing the data should change the URL).
- you can write your templates knowing that they won't render until the data is present, allowing Ember to handle the asynchrony for you. This results in cleaner, simpler templates.
- you get Ember's built-in error handling for when the data fails to load.

A username component that appears on many pages typically belongs fairly high in the route hierarchy anyway, like in the `application` template, where it's easy to load & render it once from a single place and have it remain visible on every child route.

But if you do need to use a component in many places and its data should be self-contained, it's fine to let it do its own loading. In that case you can either rely on Ember Data's store to give you cached responses (so you only trigger a network request the first time) or write a Service that handles some persistent state for your component.